# TypeScript type check problem, a string is pushed into a number array

Tags: typescript, types

`tsc` Version `3.6.4`

This code snippet reflect my question:

```js
function push(array: Array<any>, ...items: Array<any>) {
    items.forEach(i => {
        array.push(i);
    });
}

let arrayA: Array<number> = [];
push(arrayA, 1, 2, 3, 'test');
console.log(arrayA);
// [ 1, 2, 3, 'test' ]
```

For `arrayA` is a `number` array, but a string `'test'` is pushed into that `number` array. It's so wired.

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` will lose the type information about the array. You need to make `push` generic to capture the actual type of the array items:

```
function push<T>(array: Array<T>, ...items: Array<T>) {
    items.forEach(i => {
        array.push(i);
    });
}

let arrayA: Array<number> = [];
push(arrayA, 1, 2, 3, 'test'); //err
console.log(arrayA);
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxAZwBYB4AqA+ACgEMAnEogTwC5EBBMy3PAGkQDoOYoBTAWzRr1yFJgEpEAbwBQiWYi580bYHBIBRIhAwEYiALx5JMuSdLC2qTDtEBuY7IC+tqQ6lSANtyiIzlWoIYRMBBeACNuEkM9RABtAF07S21fClpWAEZWACZWAGZWAHIeNCgC5wgENDhPNnc4AHNiQNpbIA)

Comment: The answer is great. Thks.